# Error when calling QFlags::testFlag() with bitwise OR of flags

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to test if one or both of 2 flags are set, using a single testFlag command as follows:

```
myFlags.testFlag(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Append)
```

which generates this compiler error:

```
error: no viable conversion from 'QFlags\<QIODevice::OpenMode::enum_type\>' (aka 'QFlags\<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag\>') to 'QIODevice::OpenModeFlag'
```

Why does this not work?  Shouldn't ORing two flags just create another flag?  Both QIODevice::ReadWrite and QIODevice::Append are of type QIODevice:OpenModeFlag.

Also it is worth noting that QIODevice::OpenMode type is a typedef for QFlags<QIODevice::OpenModeFlag>, and QIODevice::OpenModeFlag is an enumerated type.

Sample code is shown below:

```
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QIODevice>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QTextStream cout(stdout);
    QIODevice::OpenMode myFlags(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
   
    if (myFlags.testFlag(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Append))
        cout << "true";
    else
        cout << "false";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags should be tested by one.

[`bool QFlags::testFlag(Enum flag) const`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qflags.html#testFlag) is declared to accept a single flag, for multiple flags it would accept `int`. It is also obvious from the name "testFlag" not "testFlag**s**".

```
if (myFlags.testFlag(QIODevice::ReadWrite ) && myFlags.testFlag(QIODevice::Append))
    cout << "true";
else
    cout << "false";
```

There is the alternative function [`bool QFlags::testFlags(QFlags<T> flags) const`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qflags.html#testFlags)

```
if (myFlags.testFlags({QIODevice::ReadWrite, QIODevice::Append}))
    cout << "true";
else
    cout << "false";
```

Comment: I think `testFlags` would also work with or-ed flags like OP wanted? At least it looks like that from the compiler errors.

Comment: I think yes, bitwise or should also work, if OP uses `testFlags` instead of `testFlag`.